# Change part of record with regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I work on my site in localhost, I have a field in my database which I store absolute url of some pictures, so all records are like `http://localhost/my_project/images/picture.jpg` and now in my website this records not work, I should change all records to like this 'http://www.mysite.com/images/picture.jpg', so I found `replace` command for mysql but this command will replace all part of field:

```
UPDATE tablename SET tablefield = replace(tablefield, "findstring", "replacestring");
```

How can I change just `http://localhost/` in my records with phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply strip the `'http://localhost'` prefix, in order to use host-less absolute paths as recommended in [@Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509588):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    tablefield = SUBSTR(tablefield FROM 17)
WHERE  tablefield LIKE 'http://localhost/%'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b9f/1/0).

To replace with `'http://www.mysite.com'` as asked in the original question:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    tablefield = CONCAT('http://www.mysite.com', SUBSTR(tablefield FROM 17))
WHERE  tablefield LIKE 'http://localhost/%'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d19d/1/0).

Of course, neither of these answers use *regular expressions* as requested in your question title (although they do use simple pattern matching); to use regular expression pattern replacement, you will need to install and use a UDF such as provided by [`lib_mysqludf_preg`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove the domain name from all of your url's. Simple using `/images/picture.jpg` will allow it to work on all hosts.

To replace it globally, I would recommend doing a mysqldump and opening the file in a text editor, replacing the strings, and importing it back into the database. That's assuming you don't have any serialized strings (wordpress) in your database.